# ngbModal hosed after passing component to open

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have angular2.2.1 app using ng-bootstrap 1.0.0.0-alpha.15.

I have a service which creates a Confirm/Info/Error dialog ( all from the same template with different styles).  I also have another dialog which has several input fields for user entry.

Both of these are opened using an existing component passed to the NgbModal open() function.  The component class are also listed in the app module entryComponents section.

This issue is that after opening the custom input dialog, the other Confirm dialog will not be displayed.

Here is my app module declaration ( the entryComponents show my Component classes that are passed to the NgbModal open command):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
              FormsModule,
              HttpModule,
              ToasterModule,
              NgbModule.forRoot(),
              RouterModule.forRoot([
                    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
                  { path: 'notices', component: NoticesComponent },
                  { path: 'notices/:propId/:noticeId', component: NoticesComponent },
                    { path: 'history', component: ListHistoryComponent },
                  { path: 'history/detail/:id', component: NoticeDetailComponent },
                    { path: 'groups', component: ListGroupsComponent },
                    { path: 'editgroup/:id', component: EditGroupComponent},
                  { path: 'editversion/:templateid/:version', component: EditVersionComponent},
                    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ])],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ListHistoryComponent,
        ListGroupsComponent,
        NoticesComponent,
        ModalAddGroupComponent,
        EditGroupComponent,
        NoticeDetailComponent,
        EditVersionComponent,
        SubclassFilterPipe,
        ModalMessageBoxComponent
    ],
    providers:[
        NCDataServices,
        NCBroadcastService,
        ToasterService,
        NgbModal,
        MessageBoxService
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ModalAddGroupComponent,
        ModalMessageBoxComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Here is my message box component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'modal-message-box-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/messagebox/modalmessagebox.component.html',
    providers: []
})
export class ModalMessageBoxComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string = 'Message';
    modalType: string = 'info';
    messages: string[] = [];
    input: string = "";

    constructor( private activeModal: NgbActiveModal){
    }

    isError():boolean{
        return this.modalType == 'error';
    }
    isInfo():boolean{
        return this.modalType == 'info';
    }
    isConfirm():boolean{
        return this.modalType == 'confirm';
    }
    isGetInput():boolean{
        return this.modalType == 'getinput';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(()=>{
           $('.my-modal-intro').addClass('my-modal-enter');
        },0);
    }

    ok() {
        if( this.isGetInput()){
            this.activeModal.close(this.input);
            return;
        }
        this.activeModal.close("ok");
    }

    cancel(){
        this.activeModal.dismiss("cancel");
    }
}
```

Here is my abbreviated component class for the custom input dialog:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'modal-add-group-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/groups/modaladdgroup.component.html',
    providers: []
})
export class ModalAddGroupComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string = 'Add New Notice';
    properties : any[] = [];
    model : AddGroupVM = new AddGroupVM();
    sources : KeyValue[] = [];
    classifications : KeyValue[] = [];
    subclasses : KeyValue[] = [];

    constructor(private ncDataServices : NCDataServices,
                private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
                private messageBox : MessageBoxService){
        this.model.sourceId = "";
        this.model.subclassId = "";
        this.model.classificationId = "";

    }
```

I can display a Confirm dialog ok.  I can then show the ModalAddGroupComponent dialog ok.  But if I then try to display the Confirm dialog, it does not display and no console error/message.

Is there any clean that needs to be done after displaying the dialog?

Thanks

Comment: I would love to see your complete service implementation. Maybe we can make this in to a module that provides these and I can help you fix the issue (I don't see anything directly other than the use of jquery which shouldn't be used like that in angular)